# is it possible, to first join in if condition and second join in Else condition

Tags: mysql

is it possible in MYSQL

There are three tables

1. **tasks** (task_id, task_status, ...)
2. **tasks_assigned_to** (ta_id, task_id, user_id)
3. **task_suggested_to** (ts_id, task_id, user_id)
4. **users** (user_id, ...)

> ```
> select user_id  
> if task_status = 2 
> join task_assigned_to ta on ta.task_id = tasks.task_id 
> else 
> join task_suggested_to ts on ts.task_id = tasks.task_id
> ```

Here is my sample query what I am trying to.

All kind of answers will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to do this without using dynamic SQL.  But if you show us data and tables, maybe there is a workaround for regular MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Just JOIN both using your condition

```
SELECT * FROM t
JOIN task_assigned_to ta ON ta.task_id = t.task_id AND  t.task_status = 2 
JOIN task_sugggested_to ts ON ts.task_id = t.task_id
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90222c/8),the general idea is to get all the data with LEFT join and then filter it with a WHERE ts IS NOT NULL and a COLAESCE.. or whatever you need.

Comment: But in general this won't be the same as doing a single join to either of the tables.

Comment: Some sample data would be useful for some testing

Comment: Thank you @Mihai. 
I have updated the question. 
actually, i need user id from one of these two tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can join both, and use the if statement in the fields you select.
This works great in certain data sets/tables, but should be avoided if the join is very slow or if you never need both results.
However if you have a ticked you may want to show both the assignee and the suggested assignee (if it differs).

```
select
  ticket.id
  empassign.name assigned,
  empsuggested.name suggested,
  ifnull(empassigned.name,empsuggested) autoassigned
from
ticket
left join emps empassign on empassign.id=ticket.assignedid
left join emps empsuggested on empassign.id=ticket.suggestedid
```

Comment: Thank you @sven_tore. I have updated the question. actually, I need user id from one of these two tables